# Run an application on windows mobile over ActiveSync

Tags: c#, c++, windows-mobile, registry, activesync

I'd like to run an application on windows mobile via ActiveSync from PC. Is there any way to do it via C# or C++ ? Or a way to edit a registry key of windows mobile via ActiveSync?

Answer (score 1):

To start an app you need to call [`CeCreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922104.aspx).  Registry access starts with [`CeRegOpenKeyEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922104.aspx) (there are reads, writes, etc too). All of these are also wrapped in managed code in [this open-source library](http://rapi.codeplex.com/).